# How do I animate a Svg path vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, svg

[Move.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEREM.gif)

I want to animate this path up and down (vertically). I use animationMotion for this, but my path is moving in different directions.

```html
 <svg width="698" height="745" viewBox="0 0 698 645" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">       
     <path id="bottom-arrow" d="M404.767 578.541L414.523 592.852L397.251 594.146L404.767 578.541Z" stroke="#EEE8FB" stroke-width="2"
        >
        <animateMotion
                  path="M0,0 0 50 90 0 90 10"
                  begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                  />
        </path>
    </svg>
```

Hope you got my point

Comment: `path="M0,0 0 50 90 0 90 10"` would be equivalent to `path="M0,0 L0 50 L90 0 L90 10"` Try to draw this path and see for yourself what you can expect from the animation. For a vertical up and down motion you may try something like "M0,0 0 50 0 0"

Answer (score 2):

You just need to give proper path for animateMotion. In your code it should be `path="M0,0 0 90 0 0"`

For more information, check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)

```html
<svg width="698" height="745" viewBox="0 0 698 645" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">       
     <path id="bottom-arrow" d="M404.767 578.541L414.523 592.852L397.251 594.146L404.767 578.541Z" stroke="#EEE8FB" stroke-width="2"
        >
        <animateMotion
                  path="M0,0 0 90 0 0"
                  begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                  />
        </path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Got it, But what if I want to move it Horizontally (Left and right motion)?

Comment: For horizontal animation, you can give this `path="M0,0 90 0 0 0"`
You have need to know what is the syntax of path in animateMotion tag. In my example, `M StartingX StartingY MovingX MovingY Endingx EndingY`
FFI - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion#attr-path